# ArcGIS Raster Calculator won't work in main model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, map-algebra, error-000539, error-010240

I've created a sub-model in ArcGIS, which stretches my raster data to new values.

The strange thing is, that the model works, if I run it itself - as soon as I implement it in the main model, I get this error message:

**ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "", line 5, in rcexec
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 244, in Con
    where_clause)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 47, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 238, in Wrapper
    where_clause)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line 498, in 
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
RuntimeError: ERROR 010240: Could not save raster dataset to C:\Users\Mattias\Documents\01_UNI\Diplomarbeit\GIS\DATA\data_out\scratch_IV.gdb\plus_ras with output format FGDBR.
Failed to execute (Raster Calculator).**

In my opinion, there's nothing wrong with my syntax - else it would not work in the sub-model directly...

Anyway, my map algebra expression is:

**Con("%to_be_stretched%","%min_r_raster%",Con("%to_be_stretched%","%max_r_raster%",((("%to_be_stretched%" * 1.0) - "%min_in_raster%") / ("%max_in_raster%" - "%min_in_raster%")) * ("%max_r_raster%" - "%min_r_raster%") + "%min_r_raster%","VALUE >= %max_in%"),"VALUE  <= %min_in%")**

Comment: More than likely the dataset already exists. http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00vq00000009010240

Comment: No that's not the case. I've deleted it, and I tried to save it to a different Geodatabase...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this same error when I try to write the raster calculator output to a network path that is too long and/or contains an odd character. When I write the output to my `C:` drive it works okay. The specific errors are the references to line 1, line, 8 and `"could not save"`.

One solution is to write it to your C drive and then export it to the place that you want from ArcMap. (ArcGIS Desktop 10.7). Took me a while to figure this one out.

Answer (score 1):

I"m guessing the issue is the temp workspace.

Check that the file geodatabase "C:\Users\Mattias\Documents\01_UNI\Diplomarbeit\GIS\DATA\data_out\scratch_IV.gdb\plus_ras" exists.